# Is it possible to export all my MySQL databases and users into a single file?

Tags: mysql

I am moving hosting providers and I have about 20 sites that I'm moving and you guessed it, they all have MySQL databases and unique users. Is there an easy way to export all these sites databases and users into a single file or a few files so that I dont have to individually export each one and create a new user, etc. on the new host?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL Administrator for this task?

Answer (score 4):

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -h hostname --user user -pPa55word mysql >dump.sql
```

Now edit dump.sql and take out everything you don't want. Alternatively just dump the user table

```
mysqldump --no-create-info -h hostname --user user -pPa55word mysql user >dump.sql
```

Then import

```
mysql -u user -pPa55word mysql < dump.sql
```

After importing the SQL file you will have to run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

on the destination MySQL server, in order for the change to take effect immediately.

Comment: Ahh I didnt even think of just dumping the user table! Thanks!

Comment: There's a problem between mysql versions. Mine (5.0.95) has 37 columns and the new server has 39 (5.1.73)